# Should SignalR can be considered to build enterprise chat platform with given criteria?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, signalr, real-time

As I want to build the enterprise chat platform where user can talk with each-other real time. Being a `Microsoft .Net` developer, I am aware about `'SignalR'` which can help me on 'realtime' communication implementation part.

So, considering '`SignalR'`, I want to know that- Is `'SignalR'` really good to build enterprise chat platform. I want to know that- Is SignalR is the right choice for this scope?

I am envisioning following things with enterprise chat platform.

- 60,000 concurrent request of chats (Considering 1 line chat as a single http request)
- 15,000 users

I need to know following things with respect of 'SingnalR' usage to build chat platform.

- Can Singnal is efficient to bare the load of these much request?
- How about the security consideration with SinglalR?
- I also need to provide same chat platform on leading Mobile OS. (E.g. iOS, Android and Windows Phone)
- Can I use SingalR if my client want to chat on older browsers?
- Can I easily scale chat platform with SingnalR in future?
- How about the future with SignalR? Because it would be difficult job change the chat platform that needs to re-written in another tool after 10-15 years later.

If NOT SingnalR, then what would be the other options?

Would anybody please do let know if SignalR is the right choice OR not in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JamesWorld Do you want me to move this question to  programmers.stackexchange.com ? I would be happy to do so.

Comment: I would - you might get a better response if you do as well.

Comment: Also I presume you or your client have a compelling reason not to go with an established commercial platform; this is a very congested product space.

Comment: @JamesWorld **[Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl)**. See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: @gnat Thanks for the advice. Do you think there is an appropriate place for this question? Outside the context of this site (and programmers.se) and whilst lacking in specifics it's not too bad a question.  Although  lack of architectural experience  is self evident, the problem is common. Maybe http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic?

Comment: @JamesWorld check the [meta guidance](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487) referred in prior comment, there is a section "Is there a place where I can ask such questions?"

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Yes.

I have SignalR in multiple projects with medium to high load(highest load I've seen is just over 80k messages within a matter of seconds) during testing I have seen much higher loads and SignalR always coped just fine.

Also wort noting that Jabbr(http://about.jabbr.net/) is built on SignalR and they have much higher loads than I will ever see.

Comment: where do you host your SingalR server? In the cloud or regular Windows server?